# best practice for navigating through hrefs with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am building a web **scraper** that downloads csv files from a website. I have to login to multiple user accounts in order to download all the files.  I also have to navigate through several hrefs to reach these files for each user account.  I've decided to use Scrapy spiders in order to complete this task. Here's the code I have so far:

I store the username and password info in a dictionary

```
 def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request(url = "https://external.lacare.org/provportal/", callback = self.login)

 def login(self, response):
    for uname, upass in login_info.items():      
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata = {'username': uname,
                        'password': upass,
                        },
            dont_filter = True,
            callback = self.after_login
            )
```

I then navigate through the web pages by finding all href links in each response.

```
def after_login(self, response):
    hxs = scrapy.Selector(response)
    all_links = hxs.xpath('*//a/@href').extract()
    for link in all_links:
        if 'listReports' in link:
            url_join = response.urljoin(link)
            return scrapy.Request(
                url = url_join,
                dont_filter = True,
                callback = self.reports
                )
    return

def reports(self, response):
    hxs = scrapy.Selector(response)
    all_links = hxs.xpath('*//a/@href').extract()
    for link in all_links:
        url_join = response.urljoin(link)
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url = url_join,
            dont_filter = True,
            callback = self.select_year
            )
            
    return
```

I then crawl through each href on the page and check the response to see if I can keep going. This portion of the code seems excessive to me, but I am not sure how else to approach it.

```
def select_year(self, response):
    if '>2017' in str(response.body):
        hxs = scrapy.Selector(response)
        all_links = hxs.xpath('*//a/@href').extract()
        for link in all_links:
            url_join = response.urljoin(link)
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url = url_join,
                dont_filter = True,
                callback = self.select_elist
                )
    return

 def select_elist(self, response):
    if '>Elists' in str(response.body):
        hxs = scrapy.Selector(response)
        all_links = hxs.xpath('*//a/@href').extract()
        for link in all_links:
            url_join = response.urljoin(link)
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url = url_join,
                dont_filter = True,
                callback = self.select_company
                )
```

Everything works fine, but as I said it does seem excessive to crawl through each href on the page. I wrote a script for this website in Selenium, and was able to select the correct hrefs by using the select_by_partial_link_text() method. I've searched for something comparable to that in scrapy, but it seems like scrapy navigation is based strickly on xpath and css name.

**Is this how Scrapy is meant to be used in this scenario? Is there anything I can do to make the scraping process less redundant?**

This is my first working scrapy spider, so go easy on me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to extract only links with certain substring in link text, you can use LinkExtractor with following XPath:

```
LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//a[contains(text(), "substring to find")]').extract_links(response)
```

as `LinkExtractor` is the proper way to extract and process links in Scrapy.

Docs:  https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for